# How to start selenium web-driver using typeScript?

Tags: typescript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am trying to start a UI Automation project that I have to do with Selenium and using typeScript. Could someone share how to do the same? I have used Selenium WebDriver with Java.
I have installed nodejs & npm on my machine.

Comment: please share any piece of code that you have tried.

Comment: @FurqanAziz, I am unable to do anything at all. Hardly able to understand how it will really work. I am referring to some content that is available but its all based in javaScript. I am new to both. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can start by

1. Downloading [Chromedriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and put that in PATH
2. Clone [this repo](https://github.com/nilaydshah/MochaTypescriptTest-101/) and `cd MochaTypescriptTest-101/`
3. `npm install`
4. `mocha test\SeleniumDemo.test.js`

This is not exactly what you are looking for but it contains tests to get you started with selenium and typescript. Just look at their configuration and you will be good to go. For more details, you can have a look at [this link](https://www.nilayshah.in/2019/03/31/ui-test-automation-with-node-js-typescript-mocha-and-selenium/) which contains the following tests

```
before – initializes chrome driver

before(function () {
    // initializing chrome driver 
    driver = new webdriver.Builder() 
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()) 
    .build();

    // maximizing chrome browser 
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
});

afterEach – takes screenshot if test case fails, collects logs etc

afterEach(function () {
    let testCaseName: string = this.currentTest.title; 
    let testCaseStatus: string = this.currentTest.state; 

    if (testCaseStatus === 'failed') { 
        console.log(`Test: ${testCaseName}, Status: Failed!`);

        // capturing screenshot if test fails 
        driver.takeScreenshot().then((data) => { 
            let screenshotPath = `TestResults/Screenshots/${testCaseName}.png`; 
            console.log(`Saving Screenshot as: ${screenshotPath}`); 
            fs.writeFileSync(screenshotPath, data, 'base64'); 
        }); 
    } else if (testCaseStatus === 'passed') { 
        console.log(`Test: ${testCaseName}, Status: Passed!`); 
    } else { 
        console.log(`Test: ${testCaseName}, Status: Unknown!`); 
    } 
});

after – closes browser

after(function () {
    driver.quit();
});

it – performs test operation and validates result. e.g. open bing.com and search for a text

it('should search for nilay shah at bing.com', function () {
    let Url: string = `http://www.bing.com`;
    return driver.get(Url).then(function () {
    console.log(`Page "${Url}" opened`);
    }).then(() => {
        return driver.getCurrentUrl().then((currentUrl) => {
            currentUrl.should.include(
            `www.bing.com`,
            `Expected url: www.bing.com, Actual url: ${currentUrl}`);
        }).then(() => {
            let searchBox = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q'));
            searchBox.sendKeys('nilay shah');
            return searchBox.getAttribute('value').then((value) => {
                value.should.equal('nilay shah');
            });
        });
    });
});
```